# String input scanf for struct

Tags: c, input, struct

[This is the question  consisting of 1st stage, 2nd stage and 3rd stage.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1BpQOVVU7fKZUVO9Mj3JQDli0dsAJ1yux?usp=sharing)

This is the code for 1st stage and it works well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

struct PERSON {
char name[20];
char phoneNumber[15];
char birthDate[8];
};

struct PERSON record[100];
int personCount = 0;

char nameValidation(char name[]) {
rewind(stdin);
scanf("%s", name);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++) {
    if (strlen(name) > 20) {
        printf("Name must be less than 20 characters. Please try again\n");
        printf("Name: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return nameValidation(name);
    }
    if ((name[i] < 'a' || name[i] > 'z') && (name[i] < 'A' || name[i] > 'Z')) {
        printf("Invalid name. Please try again.\n");
        printf("Name: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return nameValidation(name);
    }
}
return *name;
}
char phoneNumValidation(char phoneNumber[]) {
rewind(stdin);
scanf("%s", phoneNumber);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(phoneNumber); i++) {
    if (strlen(phoneNumber) > 15) {
        printf("Phone number must be less than 15 characters. Please try again\n");
        printf("Phone number: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return phoneNumValidation(phoneNumber);
    }
    if (phoneNumber[i] < '0' || phoneNumber[i] > '9') {
        printf("Invalid phone number. Please try again.\n");
        printf("Phone number: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return phoneNumValidation(phoneNumber);
    }
}
return *phoneNumber;
}
char birthDateValidation(char birthDate[]) {
rewind(stdin);
scanf("%s", birthDate);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(birthDate); i++) {
    if (strlen(birthDate) > 8) {
        printf("Birth date must be less than 8 characters. Please try again\n");
        printf("Birth date: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return birthDateValidation(birthDate);
    }
    if (birthDate[i] < '0' || birthDate[i] > '9') {
        printf("Invalid birth date. Please try again.\n");
        printf("Birth date: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return birthDateValidation(birthDate);
    }
}
return *birthDate;
}
int choiceValidation(char statement[], int min, int max) {
    int choice;
    printf("%s", statement);
    rewind(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    if (choice < min || choice > max) {
        printf("Invalid choice. Please try again.\n");
        return choiceValidation(statement, min, max);
    }
    return choice;
}

void registration() {
printf("Name: ");
nameValidation(record[personCount].name);

printf("Phone_number: ");
phoneNumValidation(record[personCount].phoneNumber);

printf("Birth: ");
birthDateValidation(record[personCount].birthDate);

personCount++;
printf("<<%d>>\n", personCount);
}
void showAll() {
for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++) {
    printf("%s %s %s\n", record[i].name, record[i].phoneNumber, record[i].birthDate);
}
}
void deleteFunction() {
char name[20];
printf("Name: ");
nameValidation(name);
for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++) {
    if (strcmp(name, record[i].name) == 0) {
        for (int j = i; j < personCount; j++) {
            strcpy(record[j].name, record[j + 1].name);
            strcpy(record[j].phoneNumber, record[j + 1].phoneNumber);
            strcpy(record[j].birthDate, record[j + 1].birthDate);
        }
        personCount--;
        return;
    }
}
}
void findByBirth() {
char birthMonth[3], getBirthMonth[3];
int position = 5, length = 2, check = 0;

printf("Birth month: ");
birthDateValidation(birthMonth);
for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++) {
    while (check < length) {
        getBirthMonth[check] = record[i].birthDate[position + check - 1];
        check++;
    }
    if (strncmp(birthMonth, getBirthMonth, 2) == 0) {
        printf("%s %s %s\n", record[i].name, record[i].phoneNumber, record[i].birthDate);
    }
}

}

int main() {
int menuNum;
do {
    printf("*****Menu*****\n");
    printf("<1.Registration><2.ShowAll><3.Delete><4.FindByBirth><5.Exit>\n");

    menuNum = choiceValidation("Enter the menu number: ", 1, 5);

    switch (menuNum) {
    case 1:registration(); break;
    case 2:showAll(); break;
    case 3:deleteFunction(); break;
    case 4:findByBirth(); break;
    case 5:exit(-1); break;
    }
} while (menuNum != 5);

return 0;
}
```

And this is the code for 2nd stage where I modified according to the question but I encountered error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

struct PERSON {
char *name;
char *phoneNumber;
char *birthDate;
};

struct PERSON **record;
int personCount = 0;

char nameValidation(char name[]) {
rewind(stdin);
scanf("%s", name);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++) {
    if (strlen(name) > 20) {
        printf("Name must be less than 20 characters. Please try again\n");
        printf("Name: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return nameValidation(name);
    }
    if ((name[i] < 'a' || name[i] > 'z') && (name[i] < 'A' || name[i] > 'Z')) {
        printf("Invalid name. Please try again.\n");
        printf("Name: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return nameValidation(name);
    }
}
return *name;
}
char phoneNumValidation(char phoneNumber[]) {
rewind(stdin);
scanf("%s", phoneNumber);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(phoneNumber); i++) {
    if (strlen(phoneNumber) > 15) {
        printf("Phone number must be less than 15 characters. Please try again\n");
        printf("Phone number: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return phoneNumValidation(phoneNumber);
    }
    if (phoneNumber[i] < '0' || phoneNumber[i] > '9') {
        printf("Invalid phone number. Please try again.\n");
        printf("Phone number: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return phoneNumValidation(phoneNumber);
    }
}
return *phoneNumber;
}
char birthDateValidation(char birthDate[]) {
rewind(stdin);
scanf("%s", birthDate);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(birthDate); i++) {
    if (strlen(birthDate) > 8) {
        printf("Birth date must be less than 8 characters. Please try again\n");
        printf("Birth date: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return birthDateValidation(birthDate);
    }
    if (birthDate[i] < '0' || birthDate[i] > '9') {
        printf("Invalid birth date. Please try again.\n");
        printf("Birth date: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return birthDateValidation(birthDate);
    }
}
return *birthDate;
}
int choiceValidation(char statement[], int min, int max) {
    int choice;
    printf("%s", statement);
    rewind(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    if (choice < min || choice > max) {
        printf("Invalid choice. Please try again.\n");
        return choiceValidation(statement, min, max);
    }
    return choice;
}

void registration() {
printf("Name: ");
nameValidation(record[personCount].name);

printf("Phone_number: ");
phoneNumValidation(record[personCount].phoneNumber);

printf("Birth: ");
birthDateValidation(record[personCount].birthDate);

personCount++;
printf("<<%d>>\n", personCount);
}
void showAll() {
for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++) {
    printf("%s %s %s\n", record[i].name, record[i].phoneNumber, record[i].birthDate);
}
}
void deleteFunction() {
char name[20];
printf("Name: ");
nameValidation(name);
for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++) {
    if (strcmp(name, record[i].name) == 0) {
        for (int j = i; j < personCount; j++) {
            strcpy(record[j].name, record[j + 1].name);
            strcpy(record[j].phoneNumber, record[j + 1].phoneNumber);
            strcpy(record[j].birthDate, record[j + 1].birthDate);
        }
        personCount--;
        return;
    }
}
}
void findByBirth() {
char birthMonth[3], getBirthMonth[3];
int position = 5, length = 2, check = 0;

printf("Birth month: ");
birthDateValidation(birthMonth);
for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++) {
    while (check < length) {
        getBirthMonth[check] = record[i].birthDate[position + check - 1];
        check++;
    }
    if (strncmp(birthMonth, getBirthMonth, 2) == 0) {
        printf("%s %s %s\n", record[i].name, record[i].phoneNumber, record[i].birthDate);
    }
}

}

int main() {
int menuNum;

printf("Max_num: ");
scanf("%d", &max_num);

do {
    printf("*****Menu*****\n");
    printf("<1.Registration><2.ShowAll><3.Delete><4.FindByBirth><5.Exit>\n");

    menuNum = choiceValidation("Enter the menu number: ", 1, 5);

    switch (menuNum) {
    case 1:
        if(personCount < n)
        {
            registration(n); 
            personCount++;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("OVERFLOW\n");
            break;
        }
    case 2:showAll(); break;
    case 3:deleteFunction(); break;
    case 4:findByBirth(); break;
    case 5:exit(-1); break;
    }
} while (menuNum != 5);

return 0;
}
```

I received error messages when compiling, so I follow the error messages where I need to change all the . to ->.

And it can be compiled and run.

I manage to input max_num and menuNum.

When I input menuNum 1 (void registration), I try to input the name, but the program stops immediately.

Where did I go wrong?

This is the code after I change all the . to ->

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

struct PERSON {
char *name;
char *phoneNumber;
char *birthDate;
};

struct PERSON **record;
int personCount = 0;

char nameValidation(char name[]) {
rewind(stdin);
scanf("%s", name);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++) {
    if (strlen(name) > 20) {
        printf("Name must be less than 20 characters. Please try again\n");
        printf("Name: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return nameValidation(name);
    }
    if ((name[i] < 'a' || name[i] > 'z') && (name[i] < 'A' || name[i] > 'Z')) {
        printf("Invalid name. Please try again.\n");
        printf("Name: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return nameValidation(name);
    }
}
return *name;
}
char phoneNumValidation(char phoneNumber[]) {
rewind(stdin);
scanf("%s", phoneNumber);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(phoneNumber); i++) {
    if (strlen(phoneNumber) > 15) {
        printf("Phone number must be less than 15 characters. Please try again\n");
        printf("Phone number: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return phoneNumValidation(phoneNumber);
    }
    if (phoneNumber[i] < '0' || phoneNumber[i] > '9') {
        printf("Invalid phone number. Please try again.\n");
        printf("Phone number: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return phoneNumValidation(phoneNumber);
    }
}
return *phoneNumber;
}
char birthDateValidation(char birthDate[]) {
rewind(stdin);
scanf("%s", birthDate);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(birthDate); i++) {
    if (strlen(birthDate) > 8) {
        printf("Birth date must be less than 8 characters. Please try again\n");
        printf("Birth date: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return birthDateValidation(birthDate);
    }
    if (birthDate[i] < '0' || birthDate[i] > '9') {
        printf("Invalid birth date. Please try again.\n");
        printf("Birth date: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return birthDateValidation(birthDate);
    }
}
return *birthDate;
}
int choiceValidation(char statement[], int min, int max) {
    int choice;
    printf("%s", statement);
    rewind(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    if (choice < min || choice > max) {
        printf("Invalid choice. Please try again.\n");
        return choiceValidation(statement, min, max);
    }
    return choice;
 }


void registration() {
printf("Name: ");
nameValidation(record[personCount]->name);

printf("Phone_number: ");
phoneNumValidation(record[personCount]->phoneNumber);

printf("Birth: ");
birthDateValidation(record[personCount]->birthDate);

personCount++;
printf("<<%d>>\n", personCount);
}

void showAll() {
for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++) {
    
    printf("%s %s %s\n", record[i]->name, record[i]->phoneNumber, record[i]->birthDate);
}
}


void deleteFunction() {
char name[20];
printf("Name: ");
nameValidation(name);
for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++) {
    
    if (strcmp(name, record[i]->name) == 0) {
        for (int j = i; j < personCount; j++) {
            
            
            strcpy(record[j]->name, record[j + 1]->name);
            strcpy(record[j]->phoneNumber, record[j + 1]->phoneNumber);
            strcpy(record[j]->birthDate, record[j + 1]->birthDate);
        }
        personCount--;
        return;
    }
}
}


void findByBirth() {
char birthMonth[3], getBirthMonth[3];
int position = 5, length = 2, check = 0;

printf("Birth month: ");
birthDateValidation(birthMonth);
for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++) {
    while (check < length) {
        
        getBirthMonth[check] = record[i]->birthDate[position + check - 1];
        check++;
    }
    if (strncmp(birthMonth, getBirthMonth, 2) == 0) {
        
        printf("%s %s %s\n", record[i]->name, record[i]->phoneNumber, record[i]->birthDate);
    }
}

}

int main() {
int menuNum, max_num;

printf("Max_num: ");
scanf("%d", &max_num);

do {
    printf("*****Menu*****\n");
    printf("<1.Registration><2.ShowAll><3.Delete><4.FindByBirth><5.Exit>\n");

    menuNum = choiceValidation("Enter the menu number: ", 1, 5);

    switch (menuNum) {
    case 1:
        if(personCount < max_num)
        {
            registration(); 
            personCount++;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("OVERFLOW\n");
            break;
        }
    case 2:showAll(); break;
    case 3:deleteFunction(); break;
    case 4:findByBirth(); break;
    case 5:exit(-1); break;
    }
} while (menuNum != 5);

return 0;
}
```

Latest code I edit using suggestion by @itati.
I manage to input name, phone number and birthdate. But I can only input once even though I set the max_num to 3, and the program stops immediately after input birthdate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

struct PERSON {
char *name;
char *phoneNumber;
char *birthDate;
};

struct PERSON **record;
int personCount = 0;

char nameValidation(char name[]) {
rewind(stdin);
scanf("%s", name);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++) {
    if (strlen(name) > 20) {
        printf("Name must be less than 20 characters. Please try again\n");
        printf("Name: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return nameValidation(name);
    }
    if ((name[i] < 'a' || name[i] > 'z') && (name[i] < 'A' || name[i] > 'Z')) {
        printf("Invalid name. Please try again.\n");
        printf("Name: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return nameValidation(name);
    }
}
return *name;
}
char phoneNumValidation(char phoneNumber[]) {
rewind(stdin);
scanf("%s", phoneNumber);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(phoneNumber); i++) {
    if (strlen(phoneNumber) > 15) {
        printf("Phone number must be less than 15 characters. Please try again\n");
        printf("Phone number: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return phoneNumValidation(phoneNumber);
    }
    if (phoneNumber[i] < '0' || phoneNumber[i] > '9') {
        printf("Invalid phone number. Please try again.\n");
        printf("Phone number: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return phoneNumValidation(phoneNumber);
    }
}
return *phoneNumber;
}
char birthDateValidation(char birthDate[]) {
rewind(stdin);
scanf("%s", birthDate);

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(birthDate); i++) {
    if (strlen(birthDate) > 8) {
        printf("Birth date must be less than 8 characters. Please try again\n");
        printf("Birth date: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return birthDateValidation(birthDate);
    }
    if (birthDate[i] < '0' || birthDate[i] > '9') {
        printf("Invalid birth date. Please try again.\n");
        printf("Birth date: ");
        rewind(stdin);
        return birthDateValidation(birthDate);
    }
}
return *birthDate;
}
int choiceValidation(char statement[], int min, int max) {
    int choice;
    printf("%s", statement);
    rewind(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    if (choice < min || choice > max) {
        printf("Invalid choice. Please try again.\n");
        return choiceValidation(statement, min, max);
    }
    return choice;
}


void registration(int max_num) {

record = (struct PERSON**) malloc(max_num* sizeof(struct PERSON**));           
while (true){
printf("Name: ");
nameValidation(record[personCount]->name);

printf("Phone_number: ");
phoneNumValidation(record[personCount]->phoneNumber);

printf("Birth: ");
birthDateValidation(record[personCount]->birthDate);

personCount++;
printf("<<%d>>\n", personCount);
}
}




void showAll() {
for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++) {
    //printf("%s %s %s\n", record[i].name, record[i].phoneNumber, record[i].birthDate);
    printf("%s %s %s\n", record[i]->name, record[i]->phoneNumber, record[i]->birthDate);
}
}


void deleteFunction() {
char name[20];
printf("Name: ");
nameValidation(name);
for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++) {
    //if (strcmp(name, record[i].name) == 0) {
    if (strcmp(name, record[i]->name) == 0) {
        for (int j = i; j < personCount; j++) {
            //strcpy(record[j].name, record[j + 1].name);
            //strcpy(record[j].phoneNumber, record[j + 1].phoneNumber);
            //strcpy(record[j].birthDate, record[j + 1].birthDate);
            
            strcpy(record[j]->name, record[j + 1]->name);
            strcpy(record[j]->phoneNumber, record[j + 1]->phoneNumber);
            strcpy(record[j]->birthDate, record[j + 1]->birthDate);
        }
        personCount--;
        return;
    }
}
}


void findByBirth() {
char birthMonth[3], getBirthMonth[3];
int position = 5, length = 2, check = 0;

printf("Birth month: ");
birthDateValidation(birthMonth);
for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++) {
    while (check < length) {
        //getBirthMonth[check] = record[i].birthDate[position + check - 1];
        getBirthMonth[check] = record[i]->birthDate[position + check - 1];
        check++;
    }
    if (strncmp(birthMonth, getBirthMonth, 2) == 0) {
        //printf("%s %s %s\n", record[i].name, record[i].phoneNumber, record[i].birthDate);
        printf("%s %s %s\n", record[i]->name, record[i]->phoneNumber, record[i]->birthDate);
    }
}

}

int main() {
int menuNum, max_num;

printf("Max_num: ");
scanf("%d", &max_num);

do {
    printf("*****Menu*****\n");
    printf("<1.Registration><2.ShowAll><3.Delete><4.FindByBirth><5.Exit>\n");

    menuNum = choiceValidation("Enter the menu number: ", 1, 5);

    switch (menuNum) {
    case 1:
        if(personCount < max_num)
        {
            registration(max_num); 
            personCount++;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("OVERFLOW\n");
            break;
        }
    case 2:showAll(); break;
    case 3:deleteFunction(); break;
    case 4:findByBirth(); break;
    case 5:exit(-1); break;
    }
} while (menuNum != 5);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste. And it may also be useful to see how you are calling the function `registration`.

Comment: You want: `struct PERSON *record = malloc(n * sizeof(*record));` As you have it, you have too much indirection--you have an array of _pointers_ (which you don't fill in) instead of an array of the structs

Comment: You're allocating an array of pointers but they don't point to valid `PERSON` objects. Why `PERSON**` instead of `PERSON*`?

Comment: Unrelated, `fflush(stdin);` : don't do that, burn the book, unfriend the friend, drop the class, and/or blacklist whatever crap website suggested it. It invokes undefined behavior. `fflush` should only be called on *writable* streams. Fwiw, it wouldn't be needed in this code even if it worked the way you think it does (which, it doesn't).

Comment: You probably want `fflush(stdout)` in place of `fflush(stdin)`.

Comment: Post definition of `struct PERSON` and input used.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I did PERSON ** because it is the question requirement. Or maybe I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Sorry, I already edit my question.

Comment: I feel like `rewind(stdin);` belongs in the same dumpster as `fflush(stdin);`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I try to remove rewind(stdin) from the latest code, the program stops immediately after I input menuNum.

Comment: @CraigEstey Sorry, I already updated the latest code and the current problem I'm having now.

Comment: @WhozCraig I already removed fflush(stdin) and updated the latest code, but I still have errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to use `flush` and `PERSON**`.

According to the problem, maybe you wrote "loop" in the wrong place.

I rewrite a code, it should be ok.

```
void registration(int n) 
{
    
    record = (struct PERSON*) malloc(n* sizeof(struct PERSON*));           
    while (true){
      printf("Name: ");
      scanf("%s", record[personCount]->name);           
    
          printf("Phone Number: ");
      scanf("%s", record[personCount]->phoneNumber);
    
      personCount++;
      printf("<<%d>>\n", personCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: you sure you need those & in the %s `scanf`s

Comment: @Itati  Hi, thank you. I already try your code. I manage to input name, phone number and birthdate. But I can only input once even though I set the max_num to 3.

Comment: @ZarrReese You probably got a segmentation fault in somewhere, I recommend using Debugger to help your problem, However, you pass a value into function, but no one catches it when ```return```,